# Indexed all categories of woocommerce according to alphabet

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to get all the categories in indexed form according to the alphabet. I'm attaching picture [output image of that i need.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctwsX.png) . is there someone that can help me out?
Advance Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort from you to solve your own problem before asking a question. SO is not a free coding service, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with your written code.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
* This code should be added to functions.php of your theme
**/
add_filter('init', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby');

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {
    $result = array();
    $categories = get_categories( array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC'
    ) );
    // Store all category alphabet wise in $result array
    foreach( $categories as $cat ) {
        $first_char = mb_substr($cat->name, 0, 1);
        $result[$first_char][] = $cat;
    }
    // Print all categories alphabetically
    foreach($result as $alphabet => $c ) {
        echo "<h3>". ucfirst($alphabet) . "</h3>";
        // You can change HTML structure accordingly and manage like echo or return
        foreach($c as $category ) {
            $category_link = sprintf( 
                '<a href="%1$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ),
                esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts in %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->name ) ),
                esc_html( $category->name )
            );
            
            echo '<p>' . sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $category_link ) . '( '
                . sprintf( esc_html__( 'Post Count: %s', 'textdomain' ), $category->count ) . ')</p>';
        } 
    }
}
```

[image]

You can change action and HTML structure accordingly.

Comment: I am happy to help you, if you are satisfied with my answer, kindly accept my answer